# CSS applied to the elements in lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, lightning-design-system

html element in component : sample.cmp

```
<div class="slds-text-heading--large heading">
    Activity Dashboard
</div>
```

sample.css

```
.THIS .heading{
    padding: 1rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d2522a;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

I have include this component in a lightning app. The problem is, above css is not applied to the div with class 'heading'. Also, it is not shown in Google chrome console styles. I had to add inline style to the div to make it work.
But I cannot add inline css to every element because this is happening with other elements too. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: did you tried .THIS.heading{ your css }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="slds-text-heading--large heading">
    Activity Dashboard
</div>
```

if your div is top level element then you have to use

> .THIS.heading

in your stylesheet.
[salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm)

Comment: I used .THIS .heading but it is not working.

Comment: I made a mistake here. I did not notice that there is no space in .THIS.heading. This solution works. Thanks @Manjot Singh